# Call npm script from another script and pass arguments

Tags: npm, arguments

Let's say I have two scripts defined in my package json:

```
"script-a": "npm run script-b",
"script-b": "ts-node ./src/the-script.ts",
```

Let's say `script-b` accepts an argument `logging`. So I could do the following

```
npm run script-b --logging
```

Is it somehow possible to call `script-a` but pass the argument `logging` to the call of `script-b`.
Looking like this:

```
npm run script-a --logging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do, but you can pass arguments like this

```
npm run script-a -- --logging
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `concurrently`. That was the reason the usual `--` didnt work for me. 
I looked into the docs of concurrently and now got it working.